# OpenIdConnect redirects as if the user wasn't logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, openid-connect

I'm working on a MVC Project for a customer (let's call this "Project A") and we have to use OpenIdConnect for authorization which I basically got it working, I will be redirected to the login site if i'm not authorized and so on. But if i want to go to an Action with `[Authorize]`, it makes a request to the OpenIdConnect-Authority to see if i'm logged in and then redirects me to the `RedirectUrl` which is specified for this Client.
So if I want to go to `/Home/Contact` (in my example with `[Authorize]`) I can't get there, because i will always be redirected to my "RedirectUrl".

Do I have to store the Requested Url by myself and then redirect myself?
It doesn't matter if I set the `RedirectUrl` or not. I think it's a bit strange, because in another Project B we go against our Identity Server 4 and there it works without any problems.

This is the code in my Startup.Auth.cs:

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
});

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        ClientSecret = clientSecret,
        Authority = authority,
        RedirectUri = redirectUri,
        ResponseType = "code",
        Scope = "openid profile email",
        Configuration = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfiguration
        {
            AuthorizationEndpoint = authority + "as/authorization.oauth2"
        },
});
```

I had to set the AuthorizationEndpoint by myself, because it took always a wrong url. The difference here between Project A and Project B is, that the "ResponseType" is set to "code" in Project A. In Project B it is set to "id_token". But i have to set it to "code" because other Response Types are not accepted.

In Project B i also noticed that the ".AspNet.Cookies" is available on my site.
Which is not the case in Project A. **Do i have to create it on my own?**

Comment: sorry i meant ASP.NET MVC 5. I changed the title.

Comment: Don't worry about that. Pretty good first post. Wondering, what's the Identity Provider on Project A?

Comment: The customer has a server which, as far as i know, uses "Ping Identity"

Comment: This might not sound perfect, but check ASP.NET logs to see if you actually are authenticated. I'm guessing you are not.

Comment: You're right. Also if i'm using remote debugging "User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" returns "false". So how can i fix this?